# Swapping game object with another in variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

So I have two scripts one to press a button which changes between two objects, and what I want to do is be able to switch out the second avatar with others when I hit e when near another object.  the scripts are working, but I have no clue how to get it to switch
here are the trigger script and the switch script

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchCharacterScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string ButtonName = "E";

    // references to controlled game objects
    public GameObject avatar1, avatar2;

    // variable contains which avatar is on and active
    int whichAvatarIsOn = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        // anable first avatar and disable another one
        avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    // public method to switch avatars by pressing the UI button
    public void SwitchAvatar()
    {

        // processing whichAvatarIsOn variable
        switch (whichAvatarIsOn)
        {

            // if the first avatar is on
            case 1:

                // then the second avatar is on now
                whichAvatarIsOn = 2;

                // disable the first one and enable the second one
                avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                break;

            // if the second avatar is on
            case 2:

                // then the first avatar is on now
                whichAvatarIsOn = 1;

                // disable the second one and enable the first one
                avatar1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                avatar2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                break;

            

        
        }




    }



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftAlt))
        {
            SwitchAvatar();

        }

    }

}
```

`

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SwitchCharacterScript player;
    [SerializeField] private bool triggerActive = false;
    public GameObject GameObject;
    
   void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            triggerActive = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            triggerActive = false;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (triggerActive && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            SomeCoolAction();
        }
    }

    public void SomeCoolAction()
    {
        
    }
}
```

`

In the somecoolaction is where I don't know what to do to be able to switch them; if you could not tell, I am new at this both coding and using StackOverflow.

I could not find anything on how to do something similar, or I did not know what to search for and could not find if anyone had a way to do it or a video or something.

Comment: `player.SwitchAvatar()`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bools I would rather store the actual reference:

```
public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SwitchCharacterScript player;
    
   void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.TryGetComponent<SwitchCharacterScript>(out var switchCharacer))
        {
            player = switcCharacter;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (player.gameObject == other.gameObject)
        {
            player = null;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (player && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            player.SwitchAvatar();
        }
    }
}
```

---

In general to be a bit more dynamic I would rather use an array for the characters and do e.g.

```
public class SwitchCharacterScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // references to controlled game objects
    public GameObject[] avatars;

    // variable contains which avatar is on and active
    private int whichAvatarIsOn = -1;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        foreach(var avatar in avatars)
        {
            avatar.SetActive(false);
        }

        SwitchAvatar();
    }

    // public method to switch avatars by pressing the UI button
    public void SwitchAvatar()
    {
        if(whichAvatarIsOn > 0 && whichAvatarIsOn < avatars.Length)
        {
            avatars[whichAvatarIsOn].SetActive(false);
        }

        whichAvatarIsOn = (whichAvatarIsOn + 1) % avatars.Length;

        avatars[whichAvatarIsOn].SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but it is not working and I don't know how to fix it